# Proving $\Gamma$ function is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

I saw this question yesterday in stack-exchange ,but it was suddenly deleted by OP. Fortunately , i could find the original question thanks to the source given by OP.

According to OP , the function $\Gamma$ is a group , but i think that it is not a group because it has $2$ distinct identity element. I want you to correct my answer or give me a neat proof that show why $\Gamma$ is a group.

Let me write the question :  Let $m,n \in R$ and $m \neq0$. There is a function such that $\gamma_{m,n}:R \rightarrow R$ is defined by $\gamma_{m,n}(a):ma+n$.  Let $\Gamma =\{\gamma_{m,n}:m \in R-\{0\},n \in R\}$ the set of all functions of these types. Then , show that whether $\Gamma$ is group or not under the composition of functions.

We know that $\Gamma$ should satify the all of four conditions to be a group. When i composite them , it became clousure under the composition . However , the identity element broke to be group because let us say that $ma+n$ be the identity then $m(ma+n)+n =ma+n$ should be satisfied.According to the question $m$ cannot be zero ,so it is obvious that $n=0$ and $m=+1,-1$ . That's, there are two identity such as $1a+0$ and $-1a+0$.

If my thought is wrong , i hope to see an elegant proof for this question.

Comment: Your argument is that if $\gamma_{m,n}$ is an identity element, then $n=0$ and $m^2=1$. But this is just one implication: a *necessary* condition. You have not shown it is *sufficient*. that is: it is really the case that both $\gamma_{-1,0}$ *and* $\gamma_{1,0}$ are identity elements? Does the first one satisfy $\gamma_{-1,0}\circ\gamma_{2,0} = \gamma_{2,0}$, for example?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh , i see my mistake. By the way , how can i show that $\Gamma$ is not empty set because to be group it must be nonempty

Comment: By exhibiting any member of it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin for example if i say 2a-3 is a member of it , will it be okey

Answer (score 1):

First off, $\Gamma$ is most certainly not a function. It is, however, a group: as you say, it satisfies all of the axioms, and in any group, if we have two distinct identity elements $a$ and $b$, then we have $a = ab = b$, so we can have only one identity element.

In your particular case, $\gamma_{-1,0}$ is not an identity element, because $\gamma_{1,0} \circ \gamma_{-1,0} = \gamma_{-1,0}$, not $\gamma_{1,0}$. I have no idea where you got the idea that $m(ma+n) +n = ma+n$ is a sufficient condition to be the identity of this group, but it most certainly is not.

Comment: then , is the identity element $1a+0$ ,i.e, $a$ ?

Comment: @webooo Well, the function $a \mapsto a$, but yes.

Comment: "I have no idea where you got the idea ...." , i thought that $e * e=e$ and i should check $e*x,$ and $x*e$ . Right ?

Comment: @weboooIt Yes, but that isn't what you did.

Answer (score 0):

When looking for the identity, we get that $ma+n=a\implies m=1,n=0$.  So the identity function is the identity of the group (of course you have to check that the other conditions are met).

Comment: I found that identity function ,i.e, $\gamma_{m,n}(a)=a$ is identity elemet and the inverse is $\frac{a-n}{m}$ for all functions. Is my solution right? I hesitated

Comment: Looks right.   Looks good.